# How should I structure my simple database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I am creating a database (for data from an online game) in which I need to store Players and their Villages. Each Player has at least 1 village. All Villages are unique and every Village has exactly 1 owner(Player).

It is probably important to mention, that I intend to create a new table/tables every day since the online game in question releases an updated game world data file once every 24hours. Once a table is created, I will never have to make changes in it, I will only need to read data from it.

I came up with 2 solutions for now, but I dont know what the right approach is.

Solution1:

```
CREATE TYPE village_t AS (
    id INTEGER,
    x INTEGER,
    y INTEGER,
    village_id INTEGER,
    village_name VARCHAR,
    pop INTEGER,
    region VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE players (
    tribe INTEGER NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    aliance_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    aliance_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    villages village_t[]
);
```

Solution2:

```
CREATE TABLE players (
    tribe INTEGER NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    aliance_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    aliance_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE villages (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    x INTEGER NOT NULL,
    y INTEGER NOT NULL,
    village_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    village_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT fk_con FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES players(user_id),
    pop INTEGER NOT NULL,
    region VARCHAR
);

CREATE INDEX idx ON villages(user_id);
```

Comment: "I intend to create a new table/tables every day" - wrong design.

Comment: I need to keep the data for at least 14 days so I can make some charts, statistics etc. I dont see any other way that to create new tables every day for new data input.

Comment: Instead of a set of daily tables add a column of type date (timestamp) to each table. Consider your query to create a daily chart/statistics. That query would need to join each day's tables and union all 14 sets. With a date you just have to add date to the join condition but you only have 1 join. Also, you can decide to keep 30 days, or 2 years, and not change the query at all. Think about trying that if you need to union 700+ joins.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 1-n relationship.  Each village ("n") has one owner ("1").  Your second solution is the canonical way of storing this information in a database.

Your first solution does not even enforce the notion that a village as one owner, so I'm not sure why you are considering it.  The second imposes this condition as part of the data model.

Your second solution has set up the recommend foreign key and indexes for what you describe, by the way, so it looks fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to read village data frequently, Solution 1 is not recommended. This is because the list of village ids design removes the scope of joining the person and village table

Solution 2 is the most preferred way of going about as it keeps all your options open (whether you would frequently need village data or not)

Another way of going about solution 2 is to create a cross-reference table for user_id and village_id

```
CREATE TABLE players (
    tribe INTEGER NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    aliance_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    aliance_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE villages (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    x INTEGER NOT NULL,
    y INTEGER NOT NULL,
    village_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    village_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    pop INTEGER NOT NULL,
    region VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE xref_players_villages (
    user_id INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT fk_con1 FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES players(user_id),
    village_id INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT fk_con2 FOREIGN KEY(village_id ) REFERENCES villages(village_id ),
);
```